# Python using derived class's method in parent class?

Tags: python, inheritance, new-style-class

Can I force a parent class to call a derived class's version of a function?

```
class Base(object):
    attr1 = ''
    attr2 = ''

    def virtual(self):
        pass               # doesn't do anything in the parent class

    def func(self):
        print "%s, %s" % (self.attr1, self.attr2)
        self.virtual()
```

and a class that derives from it

```
class Derived(Base):
    attr1 = 'I am in class Derived'
    attr2 = 'blah blah'

    def virtual(self):
        # do stuff...
        # do stuff...
```

Clearing up vagueness:

```
d = Derived()
d.func()         # calls self.virtual() which is Base::virtual(), 
                 #  and I need it to be Derived::virtual()
```

Comment: sorry about that, changed the question to be less vague

Comment: Using python 2.6.4 and putting print in the derived virtual - it uses the derived virtual function - not Base

Comment: what makes you think it is calling Base::virtual()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you instantiate a `Derived` (say `d = Derived()`), the `.virtual` that's called by `d.func()` **is** `Derived.virtual`.  If there is no instance of `Derived` involved, then there's no suitable `self` for `Derived.virtual` and so of course it's impossible to call it.

Comment: your right of course... been too quick again. It happens to me too often these days ;-(

Comment: I changed the question to better explain what i mean

Comment: Paul, what you say just can't happen (with the code you show).  Running the code you show, with `print "this is Derived.virtual!"` as the body of `Derived.virtual`, does of course print exactly this string (after the `I am in class Derived, blah blah` string of course). Your bug must be in some other part of code that you're not showing.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't impossible -- there is a way around this actually, and you don't have to pass in the function or anything like that. I am working on a project myself where this exact problem came up. Here is the solution:

```
class Base(): # no need to explicitly derive object for it to work
    attr1 = 'I am in class Base'
    attr2 = 'halb halb'

    def virtual(self):
        print "Base's Method"

    def func(self):
        print "%s, %s" % (self.attr1, self.attr2)
        self.virtual()

class Derived(Base):
    attr1 = 'I am in class Derived'
    attr2 = 'blah blah'

    def __init__(self):
  # only way I've found so far is to edit the dict like this
        Base.__dict__['_Base_virtual'] = self.virtual

    def virtual(self):
        print "Derived's Method"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = Derived()
    d.func()
```